# What does one red line through the weapon mean?

Tags: salt-and-sanctuary

I can see that the red cross thought the weapon icon means that you can`t wield it. but what about the 1 red line over the weapon icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [New Player Help page](http://saltandsanctuary.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Player+Help) on the Salt and Sanctuary Wiki, it indicates that the weapon should be used two-handed (emphasis mine):

> If you see weapons or armor with two red lines forming an X, it means you don't have the requirements to use the item. **If you see only one red line (over weapons) it means you must two-hand the weapon to use it effectively**.

[This link](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/834700-salt-and-sanctuary/73456828) describes how to switch to two-handed in your loadout.